# Android Lint Plugin - set custom warning / error that should be checked

Tags: android, lint

My question is if there is a way to add to lint plugin a custom check which it should warn me about before building a version. For example I want it to check all `Cursor, InputStream` objects in my code if they are closed, or to check my code for `//TODO:`, `//FIXME:`.

Any ideas if there is any kind of way to do that, or even not with Lint Plugin?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you look here? http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can add custom checks; see http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/writing-a-lint-check and http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-custom-rules .

For your specific question, note that there's a new lint check in 21.1 which looks at comments. It doesn't look for TODO or FIXME; instead, it complains if it finds the comment marker "STOPSHIP". If you want to add a rule for todo or fixme, you might want to base it on that check.

Comment: Stophip is disabled by default! how can you enable it? Here http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks, it says that you should add --enable StopShip. Where can I add that? Is it sufficient to enable it in File > Settings > Project Settings > Inspections ???